# How I can use SQL to create a new table using WHERE/AND conditions?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sql-insert, create-table

I need to create a new table with the title of the movies starred by Johnny Depp AND Helena Bonham Caster.
I have these tables:
Movies: (ID, title and year)
Stars: (Movie_ID, Person_ID)
People: (ID, Name, and Birth year)

```
CREATE TABLE johnny_helena (title TEXT);
INSERT INTO johnny_helena (title)
SELECT title
FROM movies
WHERE id IN (SELECT movie_id FROM stars WHERE person_id IN (SELECT id FROM people WHERE name = 'Johnny Depp') AND person_id IN (SELECT id FROM people WHERE name = 'Helena Bonham Caster'))
```

When I execute this code I receive one Table with 0 rows but should be 6.
I'm new em SQL and I believe that I'm making a foolish mistake. So, how I can fix this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add input data, expected results, and tag DB

Comment: Why so many inner queries?  Why not just do a simple `JOIN`?

Comment: When you ask to me add de input data means the database where I'm working on?
And I didn't use JOIN because I literally start to study SQL yesterday, so I need to learn a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses joins and aggregation:

```
INSERT INTO johnny_helena (title)
SELECT m.title
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN stars s ON s.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = s.person_id
WHERE p.name in ('Johnny Depp', 'Helena Bonham Caster')
GROUP BY m.id, m.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: What means the letter 'S' and the letter 'P' before 'ON'? When I see s.movie_id I understand that this means stars.movie_id or p.name means people.name but when the 'S' or the 'P' is alone I don't understand. Thanks again!

Comment: @Daniel-Araujo: these are table aliases. Typically, `from movies m` means that `m` is a shortcut for table `movies` in the rest of the query.

Comment: Ok, I understood.
I am grateful for your help but it still doesn't work :(.
I am receiving a table with 0 rows.

Comment: @Daniel-Araujo: this suggest that there is no movie in which both actors appear together. Are you able to set up a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with sample data so we can actually test the query?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how db<>fiddle works. if you can explain it briefly, or I can search on google or youtube. If you want I can also send you the file containing the database that I am using in this problem. Or some other way that is best for you.

Comment: With your help, I fixed the problem. Thanks!